# Delete before update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two aws task where one could be writing to table(insert/update) another could run delete query at the same time both could be running parallel queries and playing with same rows.

So the question is if I run delete from table where column_name=some condition ? then will postgres apply table level lock or row level lock. Also if a row has to be deleted based on the condition and while delete operation has not been performed on that row yet and the row gets updated(due to upsert query performed on the row), I would want delete operation to be performed before upsert.

How can i prioritize delete over upsert for each row

Comment: You want the UPDATE statement to fail in that last sentence then I assume? Because if the row has been deleted, so that it no longer exists, UPDATE will find no row to update and thus do nothing.

Comment: According documentation a DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT command acquires a ROW EXCLUSIVE lock https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html

Comment: `... another [session] could run delete query at the same time ...` Impossble. If it are separate transactions, they must have different transaction-start times.

Comment: If you want the rows to be deleted even if there is an update the order isn't important, unless the update affects the condtions for the delete ie if you are running `delete where col1 = 'x'` then an update `set col1 = 'Y'` will change mean that the row is not deleted

Comment: Please checkout the updated question.